# How to mount NTFS drive on a Raspberry Pi B

Tags: usb, boot, pi-b

I'm having problems with mounting a 3tb Buffalo drive to my Raspberry Pi B, the error I get is:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

I have tried setting the file system type to both ntfs and vfat, both give the error above.

So what do I do to get the drive mounted? And how can I get it to automatically mount whenever the Raspberry Pi boots?

Comment: did you try this ? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=215403#p215403 Worked good for me.

Comment: Also, have a look at this. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1245536&p=7822694#post7822694

Comment: What happens if you run `fdisk /dev/sda` (no `1`) and press `p` to show the partition table?

Comment: Are you are using the correct filesystem type? (for ntfs it is - **ntfs-3g** )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default is you use `ntfs` it will be the kernel module which allow read-only mount of NTFS partitions.

As this is failing are you sure NTFS is the filesystem of your drive? What does Windows or OS X says when you plug it in one of those? You can check on Raspbian using this:

```
sudo file -s /dev/sda1
```

Anyway, in case you want read/write NTFS, you need NTFS-3g but I'm not sure if this driverdriver is installed by default on Raspbian. So first make sure you have it:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Then if your USB drive partition is really `/dev/sda1`, you should do (assuming you are mounting it on `/mnt/usb` which should be a valid folder)

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb
```

An alternative to the above command is:

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb
```

Comment: I tried    sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g and it will not install because it could not find the files on the website.

Comment: I will have to look it later (I don't have access now to my Raspberry Pi). On Ubuntu (x86), the package is in the main repository. I will have to check where it is on the Pi (ARM). What does `sudo apt-get update; apt-cache search ntfs-3g` returns?

Comment: Used the command you suggested above, got ntfs-3g to install, and now my hard drive is mounted. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

i was able to mount a FAT32 usb drive with

```
mount -t vfat -o uid=MyUserName,gid=users /dev/sda PathToMountLocation
```

where "vfat" was the filesystem type and /dev/sda was my flash drive. Maybe there is an option for NTFS.

Comment: There may be an `ntfs` option, it depends on available drivers -- look at `cat /proc/filesystems`.  Note that this will only work if you formatted the drive as one big partition, which is unusual.  Generally, even if it only *contains* one big partition, that partition will be `/dev/sda1` (`/dev/sda` is the physical device).