# Can't start Transmission as user Pi

Tags: raspbian, permissions, user

### Goal

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian and I want to make it a torrent seedbox by using Transmission. I followed all kinds of guides on the internet to solve problems I had on set-up and now everything is working, **except starting Transmission on boot**.

I read from [How to enable transmission-daemon start at startup?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-to-enable-transmission-daemon-start-at-startup) that Transmission should automatically install a script on boot in `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`, which is indeed there. I applied the solution given in that answer, but to no avail.

### Permissions

I think I have **permissions set up wrong**, because I can **only** access Transmission's webportal if I start `sudo service transmission-daemon start` **as 'root'** user (`sudo su`) and **not** when I run that command as **user 'pi'**.

### NTFS external harddrive

Because I had write problems to my external ntfs drive, I tried all kinds of suggestions from different guides, which resulted in **many user ownership changes to folders and files**. Now I don't know which files I should `chown` to `pi` and which to `debian-transmission`. (I solved `Error: Permission denied` by `umount /media/pi/Elements` my drive, `sudo mkdir /mnt/Elements` and `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/Elements`, from: [How to mount NTFS drive on a Raspberry Pi B](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32890/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-on-a-raspberry-pi-b), and then add the drive to `sudo nano /etc/fstab` with `dev/sda1 /mnt/Elements ntfs-3g defaults,nofail 0 0`).

### Question

I identified that the following files are important for user permission:

- `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`
- `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` (with `rpc-bind-address": "127.0.0.1`)
- `/mnt/Elements/transmission/{downloads,incomplete}` (path to your download folder)

Also I set `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`: `USER=pi`

- **Which folders and files I have to `chown` or `chmod` to `pi` or `debian-transmission`?**

I also tried `sudo usermod -a -G pi debian-transmission` and `sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission pi`, but to no avail. (Obviously I'm a beginner who doesn't completely understand user permissions).

### Edit 1:

It might have to do with that `ls -l /mnt/Elements/transmission/` is set to root:

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 date time downloads
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 date time incomplete
```

However `sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/Elements/transmission` (or `pi:root`) doesn't change it, even after `sudo chmod -R 755 /mnt/Elements/`.

Comment: You mention a few issues that might or might not be related: external HDD mount/access and transmission-daemon issues. Just to be clear, is your external HDD auto-mounted via the line in /etc/fstab? Do you have full read/write access to it? Can you create/write/delete files and folders on it?

Comment: External HDD access is fine, both as `pi` and `root`... but for Transmission, only as long as I do `super su` and start Transmission as root user. If I do `sudo service transmission-daemon start` as pi user, no error is given, but I can't access the Transmission page. (HDD was auto-mounted in `media/pi/Elements`, but I changed it to `mnt/Elements` and manually added it to `/etc/fstab`). I can't seem to change the HDD user ownership from `root` to `pi` though.

Comment: I mean, can **user pi** read/write to the disk despite it being owned by root? Regarding transmission, `sudo service transmission-daemon start` is the correct command; services can't be manipulated by regular users per default. *" I can't seem to change the HDD user ownership from root to pi though"* If you do `sudo su` to actually *become* root (as opposed to "faking it" via `sudo`), you should be able to change the permissions/ownership via `chmod` and `chown`

Comment: I meant with "External HDD access is fine, both as `pi`", that I can do `mkdir test` as pi user on the HDD and that works fine. When trying again I noticed that `(sudo) service transmission-daemon start` actually doesn't work, even as root. Only `sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start` works?